# Non English characters in page url

Tags: sdl-tridion

basically in Tridion page file name equals the page url. And page file name do not allow non english characters or special characters.

My requirement is to have urls in french for french website. And we are using Web 8.1 and DD4T.

So, is there a way to allow french characters in tridion page file name? Or any other better approach to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The constraints on Page file name can be customized in the file `cm_xml_usr.xsd`. This is an XML Schema which defines several simple types used to constrain titles, file names, etc.

Note that non-ASCII characters will be UTF-8 URL encoded, resulting in URLs which are hard to read, but most browsers will show the decoded URL anyways.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this option and see.